# Compile error on using extern

Tags: c, extern

I wrote a very simple program on C. It compiles and works fine. But if I add extern int x at the functions.h instead of functions.c I get this error

```
functions.c:3:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
    return x / 2;
           ^
1 error generated.
```

I thought the correct place for extern is in the header file.

variables.h

```
int x = 10;
```

functions.h

```
#include "variables.h"

int calculate_items(int d);
```

functions.c

```
extern int x;

int calculate_items(int d)
{
    return x / 2;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main() {
 printf("%d", calculate_items(5));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't have an initializer in the header.

It will not work as soon as more than one C file include the same header, there will be multiple declarations.

You should make the variable a global in one of the C files, for instance in `main.c`, and then just have `extern int x;` in the files that need to access it (or in headers that they can `#include`, of course).

In this case, since the variable ends up "belonging to" the `main.c` file, you should probably add a `main.h` header that has the `extern int x;` declaration, and `#include` that from `functions.c` and other places that need the variable.

Comment: You can (and probably should) put `extern int x;` in the header file, which I assume is what OP meant by "the correct place for extern is in the header file".

Comment: @interjay exactly that was my question. The problem is when I put the extern in the header file I get the error for undeclared identifier x

Comment: @DRON Make sure you are including the header file wherever you need to access the variable. And do as this answer says about putting `int x = 10` in a C file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put `extern int x;` in `functions.c` and `functions.c` doesn't `#include` anything that declares `x`, how is it supposed to know what `x` is?

If you expect some kind of implicit relationship between `functions.h` and `functions.c` because they both have names like `functions.*` then you should just get rid of that expectation.

The normal way to do this is to put the `extern int x;` in `functions.h`, then `int x=10;` in *one* of the `.c` files, and `#include "functions.h"` from all of the `.c` files that reference `x`, including `functions.c`.